# Typescript function definition to ensure second parameter is same type as first parameter

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have this function (ignore the purpose of it, it's just a basic example):

```
const doSomething = (object1, object2) => {
  return { ...object1, ...object2 }
}
```

If `object2` needs to be the same type as `object`, how do I write the type definition?

For example,

```
interface DefaultObject {
  foo: number,
  other?: string
}

const object1: DefaultObject = {
  foo: 1
}

// :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

const object2 = {
  other: "something"
}
doSomething(object1, object2)

// this should error as object2 does not contain the required 'foo' key/value pair

// :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

const object3 = {
  foo: "1"
}
doSomething(object1, object3)

// this should error as object3's 'foo' value is not a number 

// :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

const object4 = {
  foo: 2,
  bar: 2
}
doSomething(object1, object4)

// this should error as object2 contains an extra 'bar' key/value pair

// :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

const object5 = {
  foo: 2
}
doSomething(object1, object5)

// this should pass as both objects have the same DefaultObject type 

// :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a generic type parameter to the function ad use it for both `object1` and `object2`

```
const doSomething = <T,>(object1: T, object2: T) => { // comma for tsx files
  return { ...object1, ...object2 }
}
```

**Edit**

Your 4th test works, because a type with extra properties is a subtype of `DefaultObject` so it will be assignable to where a `DefaultObject` reference is expected.

You can use conditional types to force an error if any extra keys are present on the second parameter:

```
const doSomething = <T, U extends T>(object1: T, object2: U & (keyof U extends keyof T ? {} : "No etxra keys")) => { // comma for tsx files
  return { ...object1, ...object2 }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJiAyiAtgUygCwJZgOYwC8MAPACoA0MAqjGgB5RphwQxkB8AFCAEYBWaYFACMALnZU+g4QCYJtAGQwuAazQBPEADMadRs1Yx1W3WRgB+GAG8AvjAkAiAHIg6UegCcAhsc0RHAEpAog4bGAB6CJhQFBRfbRBPGCgIehhtbAAbNAgAKBgYTwwAV08wcIA6aukhUSpqytq5GFs8trzcJk9tb2A0GAARNF6SrKgAeQE6mwKMkBAJMBKUXjRPCjmQLHWLCWhPXDx2vLzQSFhm0Qlh0fGpmVhiaznExZgRE7yohzE--4BgKBwKBp3O0BgV1kRFmhW2mHWTggqAwOHwjhOCGQ6CwRx402EIikBKgskCpx+uLYEEwIDGcDonk8SRg3jYUPgIFyMDA2xi4Cg3lwKQRRTQAEcSthigyAORvWV+DQRABu3iyJQGAAchZ4KdEQYajSCweAIVcAMwwl6FN5OEQYtpYlG4-D4x5EyEki3k77RKkwGl0rIM9bM5Jsr2PC2ytjyhaKtUagbYNi82C+ZardYwfW-Y0Fo2mi5RuoAFmtrwWElkm0KvG8nhrmKQLrReHddU9VzLvspOGptPpjPDrPZJOh50FuDY3gqDCgPhgsobnkVJlV6s1MB10rzhYPJrOZsuJIArJXbdWYLIW9jUXirt3z33-QPA0OQzu2bO2Lx4aWwhsJg3gqgMOyBt46BDCM3hjJMJIpBoWoDPuh7of8QA)

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately as it's not valid syntax, however I was able to change it to an interface that almost works, however it fails the `object4` test. Interface in next comment

Comment: `interface DoSomething{
  <T>(object1: T, object2: T): T;
}`

Comment: @GCM it is valid syntax in a ts file, are you in a tsx file ?

Comment: Oh yep, you're right. Your edit works now. It's still not passing the `object4` test though.

Comment: @GCM added aversion that fails for test 4

Comment: What am I doing wrong with a comparator function `(a: string, b: string) => boolean` that can't be assigned to an object expecting `<T,>(a: T, b: T) => boolean`?
[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAYCMyDeAoZQ5BAewFsAHOKOMEqALmQB5UA+ACjidQBpkARjwCUyALxtBJEgBsIcEHgC+ePHLDFyVKBADKYKKADmAZ3HIuTEweP8hya4ZBHkoicjjJJA1euQkeLHN8Ik1Kalp6JlJwnX0nU2UgA)

Comment: @Qwerty you can't assign a function without  generics to a signature with generics. The generic type parameters are decided by the caller not eh implementation.